# Android Getspeed using maps

Tags: android

i am implementing `getspeed` to get speed of the device while moving in phone.why `getSpeed()` always `return 0` on android ..?..i am using gps to get coordinates.

```
if(location.hasSpeed() == true)
{
    Toast.makeText(ProxAlertActivity.this, "Speed:"+ location.getSpeed(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How fast are you moving? Bear in mind that the precission of the GPS units embedded in mobile phones can be quite poor, specially in urban areas with tall buildings surrounding you. Have you tried testing this while driving a car or in a bus?

Also remember that the GPS unit may take up to several minutes to detect enough satellites to deliver accurate position and speed information.

Comment: Hi..i try it by riding bike with 30 km/h speed.its showing speed in 3.4563282363 Km/h..is that code am using is correct

Comment: Hi..i found out speed while driving,actually am updating speed value in to Toast..but Toast needs 2 seconds to update data.now am using Text View to display speed data,its working.

Comment: I don't understand this problem solution. Can you explain more detailed ? I tested my program in the car but I got speed values like 1.67862 or 1.30595 meters/second. I think they are incorrect, because car speed should be 60 or 70 kilometers/hour.